# Spree::Image.create! - can't create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

When I create an application and rake task, cannot run `Spree:: Image.create!(attachment: File.open (Rails.root + 'app/assets/images/bottle / 1.jpeg'), viewable: product) - ActiveRecord error:: RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Attachment must be present`

What kind of information is missing ? Do I need to prescribe additional parameters separately And what kind of validation I can't get through ? ?
If check the path manually to the picture, through the rails console, the picture can be seen.

My code

```
namespace :give_me do
  desc 'Load 18 products in database'
  task products: :environment do
    19.times do |i|
      kinds_rand = File.new(Rails.root + 'db/mock_data/kinds.md').readlines.sample
      regions_rand = File.new(Rails.root + 'db/mock_data/regions.md').readlines.sample
      names_rand = File.new(Rails.root + 'db/mock_data/names.md').readlines.sample
      product = Spree::Product.create!(
        name: name = names_rand.chomp,
        description: "New wine product #{i + 1}",
        available_on: Time.zone.now - 1.day,
        shipping_category: Spree::ShippingCategory.first,
        meta_description: 'Wine, is the best drink in the world',
        meta_keywords: %w[wine drink alcohol bottle expensive drink'],
        meta_title: name,
        price: rand(50..800),
        sku: rand(1_000_000..1_999_999),
        year: rand(1960..2005),
        region: regions_rand.chomp,
        alcohol_percentage: rand(5..15),
        wine_kind: kinds_rand.chomp
      )
      Spree::Image.create!(
          attachment: File.open(Rails.root + 'app/assets/images/bottle/1.jpeg'), viewable: product
      )
    end
    puts "Here are your products"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found decision.
    Spree::Image.create!(attachment: File.open(Rails.root + 
    'app/assets/images/bottle/1.jpeg'), viewable: product)

need write on

```
file_image = File.open(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', '1.jpg'))
image = Spree::Image.create!(attachment: { io: file_image, filename: "#{rand(1..20)}.jpg" })
product.images << image
```

That's all and it's working

Comment: and what is file_image in there ?

Comment: @Eric Sorry I forgot to add the file_image variable. file_image is the path to the file